# ADF Copy activity delimited to parquet data type mapping with extra column

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use a copy activity in ADF to copy data from a csv to a parquet.  I can get column name mappings to work and I can mostly get the data types to map successfully however I am adding a dynamic column called LoadDate that is created from an expression in ADF and I can't seem to get it to map correctly.  Looking at the parquet file that is output for the column "date" which is in the delimited file we get the type of INT96 which Azure Databricks correctly reads as a date.  However for the LoadDate column which is generated using an expression we get the type BYTE_ARRAY.

I just can't seem to get it to output the extra column in the correct format.  Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the mapping section of my JSON.

```
"mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "Date",
                                    "type": "DateTime",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Date",
                                    "type": "DateTime",
                                    "physicalType": "INT_96"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "Item",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Item",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "UTF8"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "Opt",
                                    "type": "INT32",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Opt",
                                    "type": "Int32",
                                    "physicalType": "INT_32"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "Branch",
                                    "type": "INT32",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Branch",
                                    "type": "Int32",
                                    "physicalType": "INT_32"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "QTY",
                                    "type": "INT32",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "QTY",
                                    "type": "Int32",
                                    "physicalType": "INT_32"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "LoadDate",
                                    "type": "DateTime",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "LoadDate",
                                    "type": "DateTime",
                                    "physicalType": "INT_96"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
```

Comment: Are the datestrings formatted the same way?  If one has different nomenclature than the other, this would be a cause.

Comment: yeah they are all formatted in the same way.  I've tested pretty much every scenario I can.  I've found others post with similar issues but no solution.  It seems a bug/limitation of ADF.